# Powershell loop performance / memory usage

Tags: performance, powershell, loops

This might seem like a strange question but i'm really curious... I have the habit of making loops like this for example :

```
do { 
start-sleep 1
"anything"
} until ($a)
```

Instead of plain :

```
do { 
"anything"
} until ($a)
```

Because I somehow have this feeling that if I don't use a quick sleep at every iteration, it will "spam" the command instantly a hundred times and affect performance.

My question is, am I right in thinking like this or can I use it in it's plain form without worrying about excessive memory usage?

I'm pretty sure i'm not but I developped an habit and would like your input on this ;)

Comment: Depends what you're doing. Sometimes it might be appropriate, other times not...

Comment: Do you think Powershell is built to "handle it" though when for example it spams constantly get-process let's say for example? Or it's wiser to do that 1s sleep?

Comment: As arco444 said, it depends on what you're doing in the loop and how many iterations you have. However, generally speaking it's good practice to add a sleep of a couple dozen or a couple hundred milliseconds so your process doesn't needlessly consume CPU cycles when it doesn't need to.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, wasn't such a bad habit after all :)